# In python, why do we always have to give 'object' as a parameter in a parent class?

Tags: python, class, object, parameters, parent

Why is it necessary to pass 'object' as a parameter in all newly created parent classes?

```
class Fish(object):
    pass
class Goldfish(Fish):
    pass
```

Can't we just deal with out passing object as a parameter?

```
class Fish:
    pass
class Goldfish(Fish):
    pass
```

Comment: That's just not a feature of python

Comment: As a side note, it's not a parameter, it's a base class. (Well, technically, it _is_ a parameter to calling the metaclass, but you generally don't want to think of a class definition as calling a metaclass, you want to think of it as defining a class…) So, you're saying that `Fish` is a subclass of `object`.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* leave it out. In Python 2, that will make both classes so-called *old-style classes* which you really really want to avoid (many nice things don't work well with them), therefore the guideline is to include it. In Python 3, omitting `(object)` is precisely equivalent to writing it, i.e. it makes no difference.

Comment: If you need further information, see [NewStyleVsClassicClass](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass). But it's probably better just to trust @delnan on this until you're ready to learn about how classes work under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about the historical reasons why Python makes you inherit from `object`, rather than just why you want to inherit from `object` (which delnan already answered):

Guido has a great post on [New-style Classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html) at his History of Python blog. It explains what was wrong with classes in Python 2.1 (and he links to [a previous post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html) that explains why classes were originally designed as a hack*).

So, why not just change everything to new-style classes in Python 2.2? Because that would break a lot of existing code. `Tkinter`, for example, wasn't updated for years,** and it's part of the standard library.

With Python 3.0, it was considered acceptable to break some existing code if the benefits were worth it, so they finally made the change: a class with no defined base classes isn't an old-style class, it's a new-style class that inherits from `object`.

---

<sub>* Also see [The inside story on new-style classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html), [Method resolution order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)—hell, just read the whole blog; Guido is a good writer, and you'll learn a lot. :)</sub>

<sub>** The 2.7 version of `Tkinter` still uses old-style classes, but if you edit the code to change everything to inherit from `object`, it works. I believe that wasn't true until 2.5 or 2.6.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, yes you can leave it out.  In Python 2, you don't want to leave it out.